# Unable to retrieve access token via ITokenAcquisition after redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, razor-pages

**Problem Summary**
I am trying to authenticate users that login to a Razor Pages web application, and then use the users access token to call a web API. In development I can get this to work and everything behaves as I would expect. However, in my UAT and production environments I introduce a small piece of code that changes the redirect URI used by the identity provider so that it can route back through an Azure Front Door instance, instead of directly to the Azure App Service instance on which the application is hosted. As soon as I do this, I am no longer able to retrieve the users token, and consequently cannot call the downstream API.

**Current Progress**
I have created a very basic ASP.NET Core application to recreate this issue (see below). As you can see, I am using **ITokenAcqusition** to retrieve the user token with a specific scope; this works perfectly until I introduce the **OnRedirectToIdentityProvider** event handler in Program.cs.

It's very important to note that the redirect URI exactly matches the default redirect URI except when Front Door is used (e.g. localhost:4463 would redirect to localhost:4463). Front Door forwards traffic to the backend service so ultimately the traffic still ends up at the usual destination, however, direct access to the backend app service is blocked.

Essentially I have two questions:

1. Why am I no longer able to retrieve the token via ITokenAcquisition when the redirect is introduced?
2. Is there an alternative approach recommended to ensure that auth redirects go back to Azure Front Door instead of directly to the default origin (in this case the web app hosted on an inaccessible app service)?

**Program.cs**

```
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var azureConfig = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
var redirectUri = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("RedirectUri");

builder.Services
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.RefreshOnIssuerKeyNotFound = true;
    options.ClientId = azureConfig["ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = azureConfig["ClientSecret"];
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.CallbackPath = azureConfig["CallbackPath"];

    // Configure manual redirect for environments that use Azure Front Door
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            // THIS LINE BREAKS THE LOGIC - WORKS FINE IF COMMENTED OUT
            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ValidOidIssuerHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("ValidateAccessAsUserPolicy", validateAccessAsUserPolicy =>
{
    validateAccessAsUserPolicy.Requirements.Add(new ValidOidIssuerRequirement());
}));

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();



public class ValidOidIssuerRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

public class ValidOidIssuerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ValidOidIssuerRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidOidIssuerRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        if (requirement == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(requirement));

        var isUserAuthenticated = context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated;
        if (isUserAuthenticated is null || !isUserAuthenticated.Value) return Task.CompletedTask;

        var oid = context.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type is "objectidentifier" or "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");

        if (!HasValidIssuer(oid)) return Task.CompletedTask;

        context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static bool HasValidIssuer(IEnumerable<Claim> oid) => oid.Any(value => value.Issuer == "https://login.microsoftonline.com/1c9f8326-793d-446a-ac80-299cce653c2e/v2.0");
}
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace AuthTest.Pages;

[Authorize(Policy = "ValidateAccessAsUserPolicy")]
[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:ApiScopes")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    
    public IndexModel(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task OnGet()
    {
        var token = await GetToken();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        var scopes = _configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:Scopes").Get<string[]>();
        if (scopes is null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not acquire scopes from configuration");

        try
        {
            // WORKS PERFECTLY UNTIL THE REDIRECT IS INTRODUCED
            var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: scopes, tokenAcquisitionOptions: new TokenAcquisitionOptions { ForceRefresh = true });
            return token;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to get token: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the risks for allowing your auth redirect to be configurable is that 1) it might point to a path (url) where your controller won't handle the redirected response. or 2) your authenticator (goog, azure, appl, etc) might not be configured to recognize & allow redirect path.

Comment: So in my case using Azure Front Door which forwards traffic on to the backend app service, how can I get the identity provider to send the response to Front Door instead of the backend service which is inaccessible? This is a common scenario that we have working exactly the same way in other solutions, it just seems to be unhappy specifically when using Razor Pages.

Comment: Is your app also running in Azure or are you only using Azure for authentication?

Comment: the application is also running in Azure